# Yet Another Tag Score Issue

Tags: support, bug, tags, tag-score

My score for the  `python` tag has been stuck for a while (more than a couple of months for sure). However, I have noticed that on the mobile app it is being updated.

---

**Web App:**
[image: Web App]

---

**Mobile App:**
[image: Mobile App]

Comment: The android app is wrong. It is counting questions too. You have 74 qualifying answers.

Comment: @MartjinPieters Could you merge my answer here over there?

Comment: oh right, thanks guys, I wonder how I did not find the other question.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like a bug, all right.

The issue is that what it's showing you is confusing.  The main site is correct; this is what you'd see if you hovered over your score:

> Asked 5 non-wiki questions with a total score of 41. Gave 74 non-wiki answers with a total score of 98.

The mobile app, however, is *adding* both scores together for a total of 139, stating that your *total* score in the python tag is that.